# Update database using Ajax and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with multiple rows that lists records from my database.
These records are projects' information and in each row, I have drop down list to modify the status of the project.
To do so, I used Ajax because I hate to refresh the whole page after update.
This is the function I created to do the update:

```
function call(){
  var projid=$('#projid').val();
  var projstatus=$('#projstatus').val();
  var dataall={'projid':projid, 'projstatus':projstatus};
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "stsproj.php",
        data: dataall, 
        success: function (data) { 

        }
   });
}
```

And below is my drop down list:

```
<?php do { ?>
<td>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="projid" id="projid" value="<?php echo $row_projlist['projid']; ?>" />
  <select name="projstatus" id="projstatus" class="select1" onchange="call()">
    <option value="<?php echo $row_status['projstatus'];?>"><?php echo $row_status['sts'];?></option>
    <option value="1">Awaiting</option>
    <option value="2">Ongoing</option>
    <option value="3">Finishing</option>
   </select>
</form>
</td>
<?php }while($row_projlist = $projlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
```

My problem is the following:
When I update the status of the first project, it works but when I try to do it with other projects, it doesn't work.
To be more specific, the parameters of the first project are sent always (this is what firebug says).

Please help!

Comment: `Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests`. So, remove cache

Comment: I removed it but the problem still persisting

Comment: you left out a lot of code. are you creating multiple forms using a foreach or something? what do you mean the first project? I only see one form. Where is $row_projlist['projid']; coming from?

Comment: `projid` is a hidden field, your getting the value of that. have you changed that value?

Comment: The table listing projects is generated using php (do {show records} while {condition})

Comment: I meant by first project, the first record that appears in my table

Comment: Without seeing all the code this is a guess, but you're using an id for the form, if you have a form for each project you're only ever going to get one, you can't use ids more than once, and certainly can't expect jquery to guess with id you're trying to reference if they're all the same.

Comment: Should I use class? Knowing that the form is inside the DO

Comment: Need to see more code, but if im guessing correctly, you need a specific id for each project form or pass it as a parameter to the call() function like onchange="call(<?=$row_projlist['projid']?>)"

Comment: I have a specific id for each project, it's in the hidden field and comes from l(<?=$row_projlist['projid']?>).

Comment: yeah, but that's an id. You can only use an id once, so you need to specify.. post the whole code if you want me to show you. You left too much out for me to fully understand

Comment: Your problem is due to duplicate ids while form autogeneration. You can see my answer with example

Comment: sent an answer I think is best for your problem and significantly simplifies your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to duplicate ids. You don't need to use ids(actually do not use id for automatic list generation. Id names must be unique). Remove `call` function from your select box and use below javascript;

You can use such js to handle that;

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='projstatus']").change(function() {
        var projid = $(this).parent("form").find("input[name='projid']").val();
        var projstatus = $(this).val();
        var dataall = {'projid':projid, 'projstatus':projstatus};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "stsproj.php",
            data: dataall, 
            success: function (data) { 

            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can see working example for form manipulating part here : **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/SYf8s/**

Comment: What do you mean does not work? You tried on your code or checked jsfiddle? While trying on your code, remove call function from your selectbox event

Comment: Yes I did it, but no data were sent!

Comment: Did you see `dataall` value when you select status of project? Any error occured?

Comment: Ah I got it, you missed the "$(function() {......});
it works Sir, Thank you so so so much

Comment: I assumed you already used `$(function() {......});`. Updated my code just in case

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer will probably solve your problem, but I think it can be simplified.
for the form...

```
<form>
 <select class="select1" onchange="call(<?=$row_projlist['projid']?>)">
    <option value="<?=$row_status['projstatus']?>"><?=$row_status['sts']?></option>
    <option value="1">Awaiting</option>
    <option value="2">Ongoing</option>
    <option value="3">Finishing</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

and the javascript

```
function call(id)
{
    $.post('stsproj.php',{'projid':id, 'projstatus':$('#projstatus').val()} )
         .done(function(data){
             //do something with data
         });
}
```